# LDAP - FInd the "base" directory

Tags: outlook, ldap, exchange-server, pbx

i am currently setting up a PBX System at my work. I´m having trouble figurung out how to connect to the Exchange LDAP Server. To be more specific, how do find out what the LDAP base directory is?
I have to enter something like o=foo,...
I think I saw a command once to run on the Server running Exchange which would show me the base directory and all the other Organizational Units present on the Exchange server.

thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The RootDSE has some information about what available contexts are.  A tool like [LBE - LDAP Browse/Edit](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/8652/gawors-excellent-ldap-browsereditor-v282) will automatically query and show you the available base DN's.

Is it an Exchange LDAP server, or AD LDAP server?  Likely the base DN is dc=domain, dc=com (replace those with the real domains).

Comment: yes it is an Exchange LDAP Server. So far i came to realize that Exchange is using Active Directory, which i can access using the LDAP Protocol, but still havent figured out how to connect. Is there something specific to be configured in Exchange (2007) or on the machine running Exchange to "activate" active directory or is it "enabled by default"? Do I have to open any ports on the machine firewall to let the LDAP request through? thx again! (btw i am not the admin of the exchange server)

Comment: LDAP uses 389 by default. Nothing is needed to "activate" active directory. Exchange cannot operate without Active Directory. When you make an LDAP connection you connect to the a domain controller in the active directory domain not to the Exchange Server. What programming language are you using and is your code running on the exchange machine or somewhere or on another machine?

Answer (score 0):

You connect to the Exchange LDAP server by using ADSI (Active Directory Service Interfaces). See the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772218%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Your starting point, to get interrogate the base directory would be the RootDSE. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676736%28v=VS.85%29.aspx